# atomic multicast (total order multicast) on netbeans java ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, multicast

i need to implement an databases' active replication to prevent fault. Sending a request from a client to insert in database, then replicate the insert request into 3 other database. After this, another ejb should read from database (each of 4 thanks to replication/atomic multicast) with something like publish subscribe. Suggestion? I have no idea.

Comment: The database should be able to do this itself automatically. You shouldn't be building this sort of thing into an application.

Comment: i need to implement the active replication. so, N resource manager as state machine receives request from a FIFO of requests in a total multicast comunication.